# jquery how to get the page's current screen top position?

Tags: jquery

jquery how to get the page's current screen top position?

If I scroll my mouse wheel to some part of the page, how do I get the page's current top position?

I want click one element in my page, then open a div which top is to current screen top.

So just put the current screen top position to:

```
$('#content').css('top','current position');
```

And

```
#content
{
position:absolute;
left:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
var top = $('html').offset().top;
```

should do it.

edit: this is the negative of `$(document).scrollTop()`

Comment: This will not give what OP is looking for. It will give the offset top of the html element which will be a negative value if we have scrolled the page.

Comment: As noted in the edit, this is the negative of `$(document).scrollTop()`, which yes, is more appropriate in this case.  But the html offset * -1 is effectively the same thing.

Comment: right. `$(document).scrollTop()`, not `$(window).scrollTop()` thanks both

Comment: You are right, but `$(document).scrollTop()` gives what you want then why use `$('html').offset().top` and multiply by `-1`.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli I acknowledged that your answer is more appropriate, which is why I edited mine.  The answer should go to you, yes.  Still, isn't it always better to learn 2 different ways of accomplishing a task, if you start out knowing 0?

Comment: Debugging in IE11: 
?$(document).scrollTop()
593
?$("html").scrollTop()
593
?$("html").offset().top
-0.44000244140625
593 was the right answer. Similar result in chrome, except the last one reported zero.

Answer (score 73):

Use this to get the page scroll position.

```
var screenTop = $(document).scrollTop();

$('#content').css('top', screenTop);
```

Comment: Perfect solution