# Position div at the top of screen after scrolling

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working with angular 2, but this questions is mostly about css (I'm using bootstrap 3). I've got 2 divs (leftDiv and rightDiv) like this:

```
<div class="row">

 <div *ngFor="let address of addresses">
  <div class="card" id="leftDiv">
   <h5 class="card-text">{{address.name}}</h5>
   <h5 class="card-text">{{address.street}}</h5>
   <h5 class="card-text">{{address.city}}</h5>
  </div>
 </div>

 <!-- bunch of code -->

 <div class="col-md-6" id="rightDiv">
  <!-- should appear at the top of current view -->
 </div>

</div>
```

So, there are a bunch of cards with addresses on the left side (leftDiv). The rightDiv appears only with the click of a button, and also only 1 at a time. What happens at the moment is, that the rightDiv appears at the top of the page (so if you scrolled down far enough you don't even see it). What it should do is appear at the top of the current view.

```
position: fixed;
```

does that, but then it sticks to the top of the screen, which i don't want (i should just appear and stay there).
I've also tried to set the position of the leftDiv and rightDiv to relative and absolute, but that seems only to work if one is the parent of the other (which is not possible in my case).

Help would be greatly apppreciated.

Solution:

```
document.getElementById('rightDiv').style.top = 
document.body.scrollTop.toString()+'px';
```

(See Top Answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be worth looking into.
[jquery how to get the page's current screen top position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019353/jquery-how-to-get-the-pages-current-screen-top-position)

Then in your CSS I would set the position to absolute like this:

```
position: absolute;
```

I assume you already have a clickhandler for your button (which shows the rightDiv). So here you could add:

```
$('#rightDiv').prop('top',$('#html').offset().top*-1);
```

(the times -1 is very important as the offset will be negative). 
The code mentioned above probably won't work right away, I'm no CSS master but that's how I used to solve a problem like that.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! I used 
    document.getElementById('rightDiv').style.top = 
    document.body.scrollTop.toString()+'px';
which worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

### This css code will make the div stick to top of screen

position:fixed;top:0px;Right:0px;Left:0px;

Comment: that's exactly what i'm trying to prevent. It should just appear at the top of the screen, but not stick to it...

Comment: Then in that case you must try this

Comment: width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
height:20px;

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:100px; height:500px; background:#00aa00">
    foo
  </td>
  <td style="float:right">
    bar
  </td>
</tr>
   </table>
```

Should make it so that it stays on our screen no matter how far down you scroll

or if you want the  on the right to appear wherever you are currently scrolled to, check this out and use that to set the margin-top: [Determine distance from the top of a div to top of window with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880472/determine-distance-from-the-top-of-a-div-to-top-of-window-with-javascript)

Comment: that's the exact same solution of "Shubham Sharma", which doesn't work in my case since i **don't** want it to stick to the top screen...